# Modify magento newsletter input box size

Tags: php, css, magento

Magento rookie here,

After moving the newsletter block to left(original in footer), the input box is too long for left column , 
so I tried add size="20" on suscribe.phtml here:

```
<div class="input-box">
           <input type="text" name="email" id="newsletter" title="<?php echo $this->__('Sign up for our newsletter') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" />
        </div>
```

but nothing happen, anybody help? thanks

Comment: try adding style="width: 100px". 100px is just to give an example, modify it for your need. this is not a proper way to do it, but by looking to your question I dont want to confuse you more.

Comment: it looks like this, seems not ok, and I would also like to amend the "email logo", how can this be done??http://i.imgur.com/W7cO3rW.jpg

Comment: As I understand from your screenshot, there should be a wrapper div or sth. Can you share the code contains including input-div, "email logo" image and subscribe button. The problem is with a tag that parent of all these 3 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set with help of css to manage size of your newsletters

if your html structure is correct like below

```
.block-subscribe input.input-text{
display:block;
margin:3px 0;
width:167px;
}
```

you can change your width of your text box.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: style.css just find this line and you can change on it